# Nexus OSS 3 - npm install requires npm login

Tags: npm, nexus, npm-install

We've started using Nexus OSS 3 as a standalone NPM server and so far it's working great but there's one thing that makes little sense to me, and that is the requirement to do the `npm login` before being able to `npm install` self published packages.

We're following the proposed repository structure:
npm_proxy - to use as proxy toward npm public repo
npm_private_internal - to use to upload self created internal packages
npm_private_external - to use to upload 3rd party packages
npm_group - to wrap all of them together so they're reachable with one URL

Now I understand that `npm login` should be required when publishing a new package, but why is it required when doing `npm install` of one of the self published packages, and can it be avoided ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not required if you allow anonymous read privileges to your npm repositories.  But I guess you've not given these privileges to the anonymous user?

If so, the alternative would be to base64 encode the needed credentials in your .npmrc file as described here:

https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/npm-deploying-packages.html

But using npm login would be preferable.